# How can I continue my proof on this?

Tags: real-analysis

\begin{align}
    f(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{u} \frac{1}{2t} \| x-u\|_2^2 + h(u).
\end{align}
 Show that $f(x) = u \iff h(y) \geq h(u) + \frac 1 t (x - u)^\top (y - u) \quad \forall y$.

My proof so far:

\begin{align*}
f(x)=u \iff \\
\frac{1}{2t}\|x-u\|_2^2+h(u) \leq \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|_2^2+h(y), \forall y\iff \\
h(y) \geq h(u) + \frac{1}{t}\frac{(2x-u-y)^T(y-u)}{2}
\end{align*}

Then if I continue, I would have $y=u$ if the if and only if condition holds, which does not make sense to me. Any clue about this proof?

Comment: Your work looks good. Are you sure the original claim is correct?

Comment: @angryavian Yes I am sure, but maybe the claim is not contradicted to my derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you assume $h$ is differentiable and convex.

Then $f(x)=u$ satisfies $\frac{1}{t}(u-x)+\nabla h(u)=0$ (first order optimality condition).
The convexity condition on $h$ can then be written as
$$h(y) \ge h(u) + (\nabla h(u))^\top (y-u) = h(u) + \frac{1}{t} (x-u)^\top (y-u).$$

I believe the differentiability condition can be dropped; the proof uses subgradients instead. I think you need $h$ to be convex though, else $f(x)$ may not even be defined.

Comment: If $h$ is not differentiable, can we still have $\frac{1}{t}(u-x)+\nabla h(u)=0$? Or we can only have $0 \in \frac{1}{t}(u-x)+\nabla h(u)$ as it is the subgradient.

Comment: @xxx222 Yes, you will have $\frac{1}{t}(x-u) \in \partial h(u)$. Then plugging that into the definition of subgradient $h(y) \ge h(u) + \partial h(u)^\top (y-u)$ gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you! Another question, why it is $\frac{1}{t}(u-x)$ instead of $\frac{1}{t}(x-u)$?

Comment: Also, when $\frac{1}{t}(x-u) \in \partial h(u)$, I don't think we can deduce in the other direction.

Comment: @xxx222 You wrote $0 \in \frac{1}{t} (u-x) + \partial h(u)$, which is correct (derivative of $\|x-u\|^2$ is $2(u-x)$). I just rewrote it by moving a term to the other side to get $\frac{1}{t} (x-u) \in \partial h(u)$.

Comment: @xxx222 I do not understand your second comment. Which direction do you think does not work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How can I deduce from $h(y) \geq h(u) + \frac 1 t (x - u)^\top (y - u)$ to $f(x) = u$ as $0 \in \frac{1}{t} (u-x)$ is just a special case $\partial h(u)$, did I miss something? Also what I am confused about the first question is should the derivative of $\|x-u\|_2^2$ be $2(x-u)$ or $2(u-x)$, as either seems right to me.

Comment: @xxx222 Regarding the computation of the derivative, remember that if you do chain rule on $\|x-u\|_2^2$, then there is a minus sign from the $-u$. If you do the derivative of $\|u-x\|_2^2$, you will not get a minus sign.

Comment: @xxx222 If $h(y) \ge h(u) + \frac{1}{t}(x-u)^\top (y-u)$ for all $y$, then by the **definition** of a subgradient, $\frac{1}{t}(x-u) \in \partial h(u)$. Then $0$ is in the subgradient of the original problem at $u$, so $u$ is the optimizer.